# Nested Webcomponents issue

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I play with webcomponents using webcomponents.js and Shadydom polyfills.

My code is on Github : https://github.com/olofweb/webcomponents-action-bar

The first webcomponent is `my-action-2`. It is a button with a title. The second webcomponent is `my-action-bar`. The goal is to programmatically add `my-action-2` into `my-action-bar`.
For this, `my-action-bar` has an `addAction()` method who create a new `my-action-2` element and add it to the shadow DOM.

The problem is on `my-action-2`, [line 33](https://github.com/olofweb/webcomponents-action-bar/blob/master/my-action-2.html#L33). When`my-action-2` is nested in `my-action-bar`, then the `shadowRoot` variable represent the shadow DOM of `my-action-bar` instead of `my-action-2` !

Comment: @Supersharp, you're right, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a duplicate.

Github project updated if anyone is interested.